# reading a number line by line and split it to multiple variable in C

Tags: c, split, text-files, readfile, scanf

***samplegame.txt***(actual_file)

```
6
2 3 3
11 2
18 1
10 3
22 14
30 19
8 16
12 24
20 33
```

i want to read data .txt file into my C program.for each line separate them and store them in the variable,so i can use in further step.i'm trying to use

```
 FILE* file = fopen (argv[1], "r");
  int i = 0;

  fscanf (file, "%d", &i);
  while (!feof (file))
    {
      //printf ("%d ", i);
      fscanf (file, "%d", &i);
    }
  fclose (file);
```

but i got all the number in one line and can't figure out how to separate each group like

```
int board_size = 6  << 1st line 

int minion_box_size = 2; << 2nd line
int trap_size = 3;
int trampoline_size = 3;

int minion_box[minion_box_size] = {11,18}; << 3rd to N line 
int minion_walk[minion_box_size] = {2,1};

int trap_position[trap_size] = {10,22,30}; << N+1 to M line 
int trap_end[minion_box_size] = {3,14,19};

int trampoline_position[trampoline_size] = {8,12,20}; << M+1 to k line
int trampoline_jump[trampoline_size] = {16,24,33};
```

Anyone has a suggestion ?

***samplegame.txt***(explained)

```
______Board_________

6       //  size of game board 
_____size of each item_________
2 3 3      //  first number in this line is Minion_box,which means there is 2 Minion_box
           //  Second number is trap_holes,which means there is 3 traps
           //  third number is trampoline,which means there is 3 trampolines
_____Minion_Box_______
//  first number     : where the minion_box are 
//  Second number    : how many step that the minion can walk 
11 2       //  the box is in 11th block , minion has aiblity to walk 2 step
18 1       //  the box is in 18th block , minion has ability to walk 1 step
______Traps__________
//  first number     : where the traps are  
//  Second number    : the block you gonna be,after stepping on the trap.
10 3       // there is a trap hole in the 10th block,step on it and you will fall down 3rd block
22 14      // a trap hole in the 22th block,fall down to 14th block
30 19      // a trap hole in the 30th block,fall down to 19th block
____trampoline_______
//  first number     : where the trampoline are
//  Second number    : the block you gonna be,after stepping on the trampoline.
8 16       // there is a trampoline in 8th block,if you step on it you will jump to 16th block
12 24      // trampoline in 12th block,jump to 24th block
20 33      // trampoline in 20th block,jump to 33th block
```

Sorry for bad english and really long post,since i'm not good in english so i'm trying to show the example as much as possible :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read the _line_ and the use `sscanf()` to parse as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file line after line, better use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

```
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // with a #define BUFFER_SIZE 1024 or whatever sooner in the code
int first_value, second_value;

if (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, f) == NULL)
{
    if ferror(f)
    {
        perror("");
    }

    exit(1);
}

if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &first_value, &second_value) != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "missing value\n");
    exit(1);
}
```